# Round a float to the nearest multiple of <n>?

Tags: javascript, rounding

How do I round a float value to the nearest multiple of "n"?

For instance, rounding 21.673 to the nearest multiple of 8 should result in 24.

And, rounding 21.673 to the nearest multiple of 4 should result in 20.

I need the solution in JavaScript.

Comment: Divide that number, round, multiply by that number.

Comment: `Math.round(value / n) * n`

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Basically: Try to do the work, and if you have a *specific* problem along the way, ask about that *specific* problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy

```
Math.round(value / n) * n
```

Answer (score 2):

There's another one, slightly shorter, slightly [faster](https://jsperf.com/niuowerasdt/1):

```
const nearrestMultipleOfN = (N,n) => n*(N/n+0.5|0);
```

It seems to deliver what's expected:

```js
const nearrestMultipleOfN = (N,n) => n*(N/n+0.5|0);
 
 console.log(nearrestMultipleOfN(21.673,8));
 console.log(nearrestMultipleOfN(21.673,4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

If you find yourself looking for the *greatest integer divisible by `n` that **does not exceed** `N`* (i.e. return 6, divisible by 3, when given 8), you might go, like:

```
const nearrestMultipleOfN = (N,n) => n*(N/n|0);
```